# Declare and initialize global variable in iframe scope using Javascript (same domain)

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, scope, global-variables

Several questions have been asked about how to *access* a global variable in an iframe. I'd like to know how to *declare and initialize* a global variable in an iframe's scope from the parent. I know I can access the variable from the iframe using `document.myGlobalVariable`, but I'd like to be able to reference it just by saying `myGlobalVariable`, without `document.` in the front.

Here's my HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
        ...
        <iframe src="myFrame.html"></iframe>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
            var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
            iframeDocument.myGlobalVariable = "Hello";
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

myFrame.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        ...
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // wait for document to load so parent script can finish running
            $(function() {
                console.log(document.myGlobalVariable); // <-- This works
                console.log(myGlobalVariable); // <-- But this doesn't (and I want this one)
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

I was attempting to add the variable to the **document** scope like this:

`iframe.contentDocument.myGlobalVariable = "Hello";`

But adding it to the document scope means that, in order to reference the variable from within the JS of the iframe, you must append `document.` to the front of the variable: `document.myGlobalVariable`.

But as my question states, I wanted to be able to reference it by just the variable name: `myGlobalVariable`.

To do that, you simply need to add it to the **window** scope instead:

`iframe.contentWindow.myGlobalVariable = "Hello";`

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 problems.

1. You aren't waiting for the document in the iframe to load before you try to modify its DOM
2. You aren't waiting for the property to be set before trying to read it
3. You are setting the property on the `document` but are trying to read it from the `window`

So:

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
        ...
        <iframe src="myFrame.html"></iframe>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
            iframe.addEventListener("load", function () { 
                var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
                iframeDocument.myGlobalVariable = "Hello";
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and

```
<html>
    <body>
        ...
        <script type="text/javascript">
        setInterval(function () {
            console.log(document.myGlobalVariable);
        }, 1000);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Quentin. I think I edited my question while you were responding. You'll notice that I was aware that `document.myGlobalVariable` will work, but how can I have it so it's simply in the global scope (of the window, I guess?), such that I can just reference it by `myGlobalVariable` without `document` in the front?

Comment: Also, thanks for pointing out my load order issue. In my real-world code, I'm using jQuery to wait for the document to load before running the iframe's JS. I've added that to my question so it doesn't distract from my actual question.

Comment: Got it. Needed to add it to the window scope instead. Added my answer and will accept it. Upvoted your answer.